# Building a new primary residence before selling the current one

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, capital-gains-tax

Our current primary residence (in MD) is under contract to a property developer, and we expect to go to closing in about 24 months.  If we build a new primary residence on property that we own in another state (PA) before closing on the current residence, will we still qualify for the $500,000 exemption from capital gains?

Answer (score 3):

The exemption has nothing to do with buying. Only selling after owning a house for 2+ years. The rules have exceptions, but this is the general idea for gain exemption. How long have you been in your current house?

Comment: We have lived here 49 years.

Comment: Someone told me that we would only qualify for the exemption if we put that money into a new primary residence.  That didn't sound right to me, so I wanted some professional info.

Comment: The need to roll over gains into a new residence ended with tax law changes in the 1990's.

Comment: As mhoran noted, the law changed 25 years ago. "Someone" should stop offering bad advice.